# Microsoft Teams App, Typing indicator duration

Tags: typing, microsoft-teams, indicator, microsoft-appstudio

In a Microsoft Teams app built using App Studio, is it possible to control the how long the typing indicator should be shown to the user? Via code or any other means. Please point me to any documentation other than https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-typing-indicator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no option to set how long it's shown from code. This time is handled by each channel.

Optionally, you could send typing indicator message more than once to re-initiate the typing indicator.

Comment: Is there any callback (that is invoked when the typing indicator expires) to know when to re-initiate the typing indicator? Also you mentioned "This time is handled by each channel." How and where is this set?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure Bot Service provides default time for typing indicator **i.e 5sec** .

Currently, there is no option to set how long it's shown from code.

But if we can use a **card refresh** process then we can send a manual typing message and when a response comes you can refresh that same card.